# how to start with Apk expansion files

Tags: android, expansion

I have google account in and i can see that there is a limit of apk files size of 50 MB, but i got to know that there is something called expansion files which will break the barrier of 50Mb file size,

i have found a tutorial [here :](http://ankitthakkar90.blogspot.in/2013/01/apk-expansion-files-in-android-with.html)

But i am still not getting how to start, where to start with,I am trying to start with a POC on how to use this.

what are all the prerequisets?

When i try to use this:

Create two library projects from existing source.

```
<sdk>/extras/google/play_apk_expansion/downloader_library
<sdk>/extras/google/play_licensing/library
```

it gives me tons of errors.am i doing anything wrong?

Please guide me on this.

Comment: If you understand French You have a full tutorial [here](http://infinitestudio.fr/blog/2013/08/20/apk-expansion-files/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've already figured this out.

Basically if you've copied the files from the SDK to your workspace, you will have to connect the folders manual. (Because they are reference correctly in the SDK)

if your using Eclipse then right hand the download_library application folder > Properties > Android.

You will see library, what you have to do is add the location of the libraries that are missing.

Add > (find the folder in your workspace)

Hope this helped!